# make a simple login authentication using java class,servlet,jsp and session and database

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to make a login process using mvc structure where i send userid and password from  `index.jsp` page.If they match with the database value then it will go to the `stater001.jsp`.In `index.jsp` i've 2 fields userid and password from.I've post userid and pwd into `LoginServlet` servlet.

`LoginServlet` process `userid , pwd` making the instance of `loginAuthentication` class.`loginAuthentication` class checks whether `userid` and `password` exists in database or not with `select query`.I have also used setter getter class`user` to set `userid` and `pwd` into session.I tried to do the whole login process in an organised way.But i'm stucked with error i couldn't under stand what is the problem please help me to solve this.First i tried it without using mvc pattern then it worked fine.But now it is not working.
Below is my previous code all process in one servlet

```
package DataAccess;
import DataAccess.dbconnector;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
  import java.io.*;
 import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
 import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/LoginServlet"})
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

String userid, pwd;
  Connection connection = null;
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    Statement statement = null;
   userid = request.getParameter("uname");
    pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    try {
        dbconnector dbc = new dbconnector();
        connection = dbc.Open();
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from member where uname='" + userid + "' and pass='" + pwd + "'");

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
            response.sendRedirect("view/starter001.jsp");
        } else {

            request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Invalid user or password");
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 finally {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


}
```

}

And in my new code here i've stucked with error in execution
[image]
And here i've attached my new edited codes where i tried to do this in an organised way .My errors have been gone but not showing the userid after login    http://pastebin.com/RKyieMqn
Please consider my question

at first when all codes were in loginservlet then it was like[image]  but when i start using mvc structure it is not showing the username

Comment: The snap shot is not enough to help you out, paste the error as well, point  cursor to the bulb icon highlighted on the line no panel.

Comment: It was showing  `surround the block with try catch` error after adding try catch the error was gone but after login it should show the name `orny` (user name in databese)but now it is showing `Model.authenticateUser@e7fc25b`.I am trying to solve it but now my jsp lage is not getting the session value..I have also edited my code here http://pastebin.com/RKyieMqn   i've added try catch

Comment: and when password is `' OR 1=1 --` or something similar, boom "open bar"

Comment: Even everything works fine, I won't advice you to use it. It is prone to sql injection attack. There are neat solutions for authentication check Apache Shiro. Spring security, if you are already using Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you pasted the wrong code:
In the below statement, where is the variable user defined?
session.setAttribute("user", user);

Perhaps, you have created a authenticateUser object somewhere. Please check you code to find it.

Comment: Yes sir i didn't wrote the right code first but now i have edited my code and my errors have been gone but  not showing the user name

Comment: where is you code for stater001.jsp? It seems you put a user object into session, then uses it in stater001.jsp by using something like ${user}, so it will print the user object's default toString method, you need change ${user} to ${user.userId}

Comment: http://pastebin.com/t8ZhW98y here is my starter001.jsp here i only use  `session.getAttribute("userid")` method to show  user name after login`<span class="hidden-xs"><%=session.getAttribute("userid")%></span>`

Comment: in your back end code, you set variable 'user' into session,  but in your jsp you get it by 'userid', that's the problem. you should use the same name.

Comment: i set userid to user but when i used session.setAttribute("userid", user.getUserId()) then it works

Answer (score 0):

I have changed `session.setAttribute("userid", user);` to  `session.setAttribute("userid", user.getUserId());` and now it's working